# CSS :not selector not working for nested elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

:not selector not working for nested elements `div.class > div > a`. In this below snippet

and  elements text shown in red color.

```css
.x-webkit *:not(p):not(em) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="x-webkit">
  <div>red</div>
  <ul><li>red</li></ul>
  <div>
    <p>
      Not red<br>
      <strong>red</strong><br>
      <em>Not red</em>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>red</div>
  <table><tr><td>red</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to do it the other way around. Simply:

```css
.x-webkit * {
  color: red;
}

.x-webkit p,
.x-webkit em {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="x-webkit">
  <div>red</div>
  <ul><li>red</li></ul>
  <div>
    <p>
      Not red<br>
      <strong>red</strong><br>
      <em>Not red</em>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>red</div>
  <table><tr><td>red</td></tr></table>
</div>
```